# pycharm showing error while importing webdrivers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

this is the code im trying to run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\mathe\pythonProject\test\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
```

And I get this error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/mathe/pythonProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mathe/pythonProject/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\mathe\pythonProject\test\drivers\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is it in the enviroment path ?

Comment: im not sure if its in the environment path or not.How can i check that?

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment so...

Please double check the path for executable.
If it's still showing the error, place the chromedriver.exe in the same folder as the .py file. This way you don't have to write the full path, just leave it blank like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
web=webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: thank you i was trying to figure that out too. it did execute but now shows the message "this version of chrome driver only supports chrome version85

Comment: chrome driver -> relates to version of google chrome you have.